# Merge tools that ignores $Id lines

Tags: merge, cvs

I need to merge a forked project. 
Unfortunately, the CVS $Id lines are different so the merge tools I tried report that all the files are different (and 95% of them have only this line different)

Is there a merge tool that can be configured to ignore line comparison results based on a pattern ?

[edit]
I discovered that WinMerge has line filters - setting up them correctly actually works.

Francesco

Answer (score 2):

I use meld, which can use regex filters to ignore.
It has some preset ones you can select including CVS keywords.
The regex it uses for that BTW is:

```
\$\w+(:[^\n$]+)?\$
```

You can get meld on any linux distro or
download from here: http://meld.sourceforge.net/
I'm not sure how it's supported on windos,
but I do know kdiff3 supports windows so you could
give it a try there: http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

well you could use 
cvs update -kk 
whick does not expand the $words.

of course this is still a problems the $log which is expanded on commits and not updates.

Answer (score 0):

[CompareIT](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm) allow to use [regular expression](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3/help/source/html/cmp_usingregularexpressions.htm) matching. I used it for automatically generated code comparison and it was very useful.