# Doing a 'diff/st' and ignoring the first line if it matches a specific criterion

Tags: regex, mercurial, diff, cvs

In a repository for a well known open source project, all files contain a version string with a timestamp as their first line:

```
<?php  // $Id: index.php,v 1.201.2.10 2009-04-25 21:18:24 stronk7 Exp $
```

Even if I don't really understand why they do this - since the files are already under version control -, I have to live with this.

The main problem is that if I try to 'st' or 'diff' a release to get an idea of what was changed from the previous one, every single file contained in the repository is obviously marked as modified and the diffs become unreadable and unmanageable.

I'm wondering if there's a way to ignoring the first lines doing a diff/st when they match a regexp.

The project is under cvs - cvs, yes, you've read correctly - and included in a bigger mercurial repository.

Comment: [this might be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202786/merge-tools-that-ignores-id-lines)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about cvs, but with hg you can use any external diff tool with the bundled [`extdiff` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension), and any modern tool should have the ability to let you ignore diffs that match certain patterns.

I swear by [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com), which allows arbitrary syntax definition.

kdiff3 has [preprocessor commands](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/preprocessors.html) that you can pipe the input through.

Comment: Another vote for Beyond Compare.  Also, I'm trying to run your PianoActor code in VSS, but its data files seem corrupt.  Contact me at camilleg@camille-g.com?

Answer (score 2):

If you try

```
man diff
```

you'll find

```
--ignore-matching-lines=RE Ignore changes whose lines all match RE.
```

search "ignore matching lines" on the web gives examples :

> diff --unified --recursive --new-file
>   --ignore-matching-lines='[$]Author.*[$]'
>   --ignore-matching-lines='[$]Date.*[$]'  ...

(http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-apps/2005-01/msg00000.html)

Thus try :

```
diff --ignore-matching-lines='[<][?]php  [/][/] [$]Id:'
```

Comment: (You can also do a diff and then a grep -v "[<][?]php  [/][/] [$]Id"... wwwwwwww :-P)

Comment: Sorry, it was probably not clear in the question that I need to do that in a hg/cvs context. Using the UNIX diff probably won't help me :(

Comment: Sure, but see the previous answer for how to set an external diff command - including the arguments presented in _this_ answer.  Between the two answers you have a complete solution.

Comment: thanks for your comment Steve, it'll be some help for me as well :D